# i cant update to datetime table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have already have date value

```
SET @LogDate1 = CAST(@logtanggal AS datetime)
SET @LogDate = CONVERT(varchar, @LogDate1, 20 )
```

@logtanggal is varchar, and i already convert it to datetime, the problem is when i try to update value of @logdate to the table, there are error mssg like

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LockAmountOnline_t24_Active, Line 108
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

the table data type is already datetime, why i cant update to table?

the update query

```
SET @sql1 = 'UPDATE Lock_Amount_Trx 
                SET
                    GenerateDate = GETDATE(), -- datetime
                    LogDate ='''+@Logdate1+''', -- datetime
                    LogStatus = CASE WHEN tlat.logdescription = ''SUCCESS.UPD'' THEN ''SUCCESS''
                                            WHEN tlat.logdescription = ''NOT.UPD-KTA'' THEN ''NOT CHANGED''
                                            END ,
                    LogDescription = tlat.logdescription -- varchar

                FROM ##TempLockAmmountTrx tlat, Lock_Amount_Trx lat
                WHERE tlat.cuscode = lat.Custcode AND tlat.norekdeb = lat.NoRekDebet AND tlat.lockammount = lat.TotalLockAmount AND lat.Id ='''+ @idFile +''''

    EXEC (@sql1)
```

converted varchar(top) and target table date format date (bottom)
[image]

Comment: Show the code that is generating the error.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You need to use parameterized `Dynamic SQL`.

Comment: Use something like https://dbfiddle.uk/ and create a table as Lock_Amount_Trx  (data type of LogDate is important) and need to have the value of @logtanggal.

Comment: i already have value of @logtanggal

Comment: Instead of EXEC (@sql1), put a Select @sql1 and see what is wrong with your query

Comment: problem already solved, so apperently i dont have convert @logdate1 to datetime

Comment: Why are you using Dynamic SQL, there's nothing dynamic about it. All you're doing here is causing a huge security flaw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is literally no need for "dynamic" SQL here, there's nothing dynamic in your code. All you are doing here is creating a huge security flaw in your code. SQL injection is **not** a good thing, and you should *never* write code that can suffer from it.

Stop using dynamic SQL and the error doesn't happen:

```
UPDATE Lock_Amount_Trx 
SET GenerateDate = GETDATE(), -- datetime
    LogDate = @Logdate1, -- datetime
    LogStatus = CASE WHEN tlat.logdescription = 'SUCCESS.UPD' THEN 'SUCCESS'
                     WHEN tlat.logdescription = 'NOT.UPD-KTA' THEN 'NOT CHANGED'
                END,
    LogDescription = tlat.logdescription -- varchar
FROM ##TempLockAmmountTrx tlat, Lock_Amount_Trx lat
WHERE tlat.cuscode = lat.Custcode
  AND tlat.norekdeb = lat.NoRekDebet
  AND tlat.lockammount = lat.TotalLockAmount
  AND lat.Id = @idFile;
```

If you do ever need to *actually* use dynamic SQL, I suggest reading up on some of the basics, such as **properly** quoting your dynamic objects (which the above has none), and parametrising your statements. Rather than putting this all in the answer (which, considering that you don't need dynamic SQL, means it's not really really), you can read about this in my article [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

Also, be *very* careful with your expression `CONVERT(varchar, @LogDate1, 20 )`. **Always** declare your length, scale and precissions when using data types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameterized `Dynamic SQL` :

```
SET @sql1 = 'UPDATE Lock_Amount_Trx 
                SET
                    GenerateDate = GETDATE(), -- datetime
                    LogDate = @LogDate1, -- datetime
                    LogStatus = CASE WHEN tlat.logdescription = ''SUCCESS.UPD'' THEN ''SUCCESS''
                                            WHEN tlat.logdescription = ''NOT.UPD-KTA'' THEN ''NOT CHANGED''
                                            END ,
                    LogDescription = tlat.logdescription -- varchar

                FROM ##TempLockAmmountTrx tlat, Lock_Amount_Trx lat
                WHERE tlat.cuscode = lat.Custcode AND tlat.norekdeb = lat.NoRekDebet AND tlat.lockammount = lat.TotalLockAmount AND lat.Id = @idFile'

exec sp_executesql @sql1, N'@LogDate1 DATETIME, @idFile varchar(255)', @LogDate1, @idFile
```

Note : I don't know what is the type of `idfile` so, change the type accordingly.

**EDIT** : As larnu pointed out that this query will not require any Dynamic SQL.

So, you can use plain update statement.

Comment: i try run your code and get this msg                                                                                  
  Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

(3 row(s) affected)
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@LogDate"

Comment: @omik919. . . `@sql1` should have `nvarchar` type & declare `@LogDate1` with datetime having date-time value.

Comment: The OP doesn't need to use dynamic SQL at all, there's nothing dynamic about their statement.

Comment: @Larnu. .  Yes. I know but, OP might uses partial portion of query. I supposed.